# Bottom Tab content container background color [REACT NATIVE]

Tags: css, react-native

Sorry for this question, but I've tried many things to change the color of the screens of my bottom tabs screens witch are gray by default as you can see in the pic, and I want it white.
Even with the `tabBarStyle`(you can find the code bellow)

Hopefully someone can help !
Thanks

[image: phone app]

```html
<Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarShowLabel: false,
                tabBarStyle: {
          position: "absolute",
              padding: 0,
              left: 110,
              right: 110,
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            bottom: 45,
              height: 65,
            borderRadius: 100,
            borderTopColor: "transparent",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            shadowColor: "#393939",
            shadowOffset: {
                height: 3,
                width: 3,
              },
            shadowOpacity: 0.15,
            shadowRadius: 8,
            elevation: 0,},
        }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={Home}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Benefits"
                component={Wallet}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Profile"
                component={Profile}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
```

```
const Profile = ({ navigation }) => {
return (
    <MainLayout>
        <View style={styles.profileRecap}>
            <IconBox
                source={require("../assets/icons/camera.png")}
                iconColor={theme.colors.pinkdark}
                backgroundColor={theme.colors.pinklight}
            />
            <View style={styles.textBox}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{user.firstName}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{user.lastName}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>

        <H3>Mon compte</H3>

        <TouchableBox
            text="Informations personnelles"
            iconSource={require("../assets/icons/avatar.png")}
            type="primary"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ProfileSettings")}
        />
        <H3>Autres options</H3>
        <TouchableBox
            text="Se deconnecter"
            iconSource={require("../assets/icons/logout.png")}
            onPress={onLogout}
            type="danger"
        />
    </MainLayout>
);
```

};

export default Profile;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
profileRecap: {
flexDirection: "row",
marginVertical: 16,
},
textBox: {
marginLeft: 16,
},
text: {
fontSize: 24,
fontFamily: "Circular-Md",
color: theme.colors.gray1,
},
});

Comment: can you share here the profile screen code.

Comment: Hello Ankit, Thanks for your answer, I edited the post with the code

Comment: so you need to change the color of the BottomTab Component or the Screen ..?

Comment: I would like to change the background of the tab screen with full white, the value by default is gray, idk why and I can modify. I could modify the screen background but why by default its white and when I add a bottom tab its grey, is there a param I am missing in the Tab Navigator or the Tab Screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer...
it's this command

```html
<Tab.Navigator
sceneContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
>
```